# Firebase Hosting how to programmatically or manually flush the cache?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I accidentally served content in my project with cache headers set to expire in one year, and Firebase Hosting seems to do aggressive caching. Even after making my service remove these headers, Firebase continues to serve the old content. I would like to know if there is a way to invalidate the cache, similar to what you can do on Cloudflare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do another Hosting deployment, it should stop serving anything previously deployed in the cache.  If you don't deploy (that is, `firebase deploy`), then the cache will remain.

See the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/manage-cache):

> Any requested static content is automatically cached on the CDN. If you redeploy your site's content, Firebase Hosting automatically clears all your cached content across the CDN until the next request.

If you are hosting dynamic content from Functions or Cloud Run, you should also read the rest of that document.

Comment: I understood, I had previously understood that the Run would not be affected, that I would not need a new deployment to clear the cache. Thank you.